# How many lines needed to not lose in tetris game?

Tags: problem-solving, combinatorial-game-theory

Suppose we play a tetris game with tetris be given randomly.

Is there exists a number of lines that we can play infinitely, i.e. do not lose the game?

Comment: By number of lines, do you mean how big the board is?

Comment: @MichaelT Yes. I mean the height of the board.

Comment: Is the width assumed to be the standard? (I *think* it's 10)